# Rewriting $\sin(a+b) = c$

Tags: trigonometry

Given $$\sin(a+b) = c$$

Could it be rewritten as $$a = \arcsin(c) - b$$

For all reals $a$ and $b$?

Sine over reals isn't one-to-one though. Is the above valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general $\sin(x)=y$ is equivalent to

$$ x=\pi n+(-1)^n\arcsin(y)\text{ for some }n\in\mathbb{Z} $$

So if $\sin(a+b)=c$ then there exists an integer $n$ such that

\begin{equation} a=\pi n+(-1)^n\arcsin(c) -b \tag{1}   \end{equation}

This is equivalent to the WolframAlpha solution but is more compact.

Note that

\begin{eqnarray}
\sin(\pi n+(-1)^n\arcsin(y))&=&\sin(\pi n)\cos((-1)^n\arcsin(y))\\
& &+\cos(\pi n)\sin((-1)^n\arcsin(y))\\
&=&0+(-1)^n(-1)^n\sin(\arcsin(y))\\
&=&y
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Note that this solution is equivalent to the WolframAlpha solution if we break $n$ into the even case $n=2k$ and into the odd case $n=2k+1$, but gives the solution in one equation instead of two.

Answer (score 1):

This formula doesn't work for all real numbers since the range of $\arcsin(x)$ is $[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}]$. For example, $$\sin (\frac{3\pi}{2} + \frac{\pi}{4}) = -\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$$ but $$\arcsin\left(-\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}\right) - \frac{\pi}{4} = -\frac{\pi}{2} \neq \frac{3\pi}{4}.$$

Comment: Right. But if I let WolframAlpha to solve it for $a$, I get [this](http://i.imgur.com/y5TIA9E.png) which seems to give my rewritten form and doesn't seem to limit the value of $a$ or $b$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Right. So that says for all $a$, there exists a $b$, $c$ and $n$ such that the expression is true - is that correct?

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Thanks for setting me straight. I've deleted the incorrect comment.